# Adding backbutton event listener only to a specific page

Tags: javascript, cordova

I'm working on phonegap and I have an index.html page where I have added an event listener to the back key and it works fine.

But my issue is that I want to override the back-key functionality only in index.html and in other pages it should have the default back-key behaviour. How can I achieve this

```
document.addEventListener("deviceready", onDeviceReady, false);
function onDeviceReady() { 
   document.addEventListener("backbutton", onBackKeyDown, false);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Keep a record of which page you are currently displaying. The callback can test whether you're on index.html or not, and if not, return `false`, passing the event up (I think).